# $_POST to a form on another page

Tags: php

I was originally using a $_GET method:

```
'<a href = "editNews.php?starts='.$starts.'&ends='.$ends.'&$event='.$event.' data-role="button" data-icon="edit"></a>'
```

Using this works, but i've been told that using a $_POST method is better, less messier and just the preferred choice.

So i'm wondering how i would implement the very same thing as above, but using a $_POST method.

Comment: Just add a form with hidden fields and set method to `POST`

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a form with method post or use an ajax request. In jquery this would look like:

```
$("#myLinkId#").on('click',function() {
    $.ajax({url:'phpFile.php',type:'post',data:{...you data here...}});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn this into a form or use jQuery to trigger an Ajax call on click. Here's a form example:

```
<form action="editNews.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="starts" value="<php echo $starts?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="end" value="<php echo $end?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="<php echo $event?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Your Link" data-icon="edit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To send data via PHP to another page/form, you can do this:

**Original form:**

```
<form method='post' action='new-page.php'>
  inputs here, etc.
  submit button here
</form>
```

So this will, upon clicking submit, send you to new-page.php with all of the form data held in the PHP variable `$_POST` which is an array.

You can access the data by referencing the array with the name of the input, for example, say that you had:

`<input type='text' name='NAME' />`

You can reference this data on `new-page.php` with `$_POST['NAME']`.

I hope this helps you!